# JSF update changed values only

Tags: performance, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I´ve tried to get some informations about my idea, but still haven´t.
I wan´t to know, if there´s a way to achieve this:

I´m using a primefaces `<p:dataTable>` to display a list of items. For updating my table if some entries changed, I´m using ***datatableWidgetVar.filter()*** within the oncomplete event of `<p:ajax>`. Because the handled lists are pretty big (~50k-100k entries) it takes a few secs to 'update' the dataTable by its filter method and there is a 'flickering' I´d like to remove...

I don´t want the user to see, that components are reloaded, I mean it should be more 'smooth'. Is there a way to compare those 2 lists and only update the changed rows, so I don´t need to rerender 50,000 items? Or shall I pass the changed items (by id maybe?) to my jsf page and select the rows that are affected? Does primefaces offer such a algorithm?

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need some code or more details ;)

**EDIT:**

I´ve been thinking about that again and what about:

1. access the dataTable´s underlying list of items (client-side)
2. compare the server-side (newer) list with the (older) client-side one
3. get the changed (modified,added,removed) entries
4. force my dataTable to update only those 'rows'

Is this a good practise?

Comment: Actually, you can determine the affected row / cell by an EditEvent. Check this here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml
By the way, why do you use a widgetVar for updating?

Comment: Just one idea/question. Do you really need to display all >50k entries on screen ? Maybe you can use "infinite scrolling" http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml or lazy loading http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: Thank you so far guys, I´ll try your posts asap and let you know, if it works...

Comment: @chaeschuechli I´m using a widgetVar, to call the primefaces javaScript function `dataTable.filter()` in the ajax-component´s oncomplete eventhandler ;)

Comment: @jNick No, paginator is enabled and shows 20 items per page... But if my list changes in bean, jsf needs to get the new value of my list, and caused by the massive items, it takes a moment ;)

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late response... I´ve looked to your ideas and some of them could be usefull and nice to have in my project, but they don´t solve my current problem... I´ve updated my question with a new idea...